# Вопрос по MySQL запросу + php

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, пользователи ХешКода.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если небольшой скрипт - вывод, в данном скрипте присутствует проверка на "wid" (типа если wid = Сессии пользователя, то выводит из базы строки).

Проблема в выводе

```
            $ticket = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT wid FROM tickets"));
        if($ticket[0]==$uid) {
            $tickets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE wid = '".intval($uid)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
            $status = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT status FROM tickets WHERE wid = '".intval($uid)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50"));
        } else {
            $tickets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE uid = '".intval($uid)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
            $status = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT status FROM tickets WHERE uid = '".intval($uid)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50"));
        }
```

То есть `$ticket[0]` выбирает в базе только 1 id и сравнивает уже. Как сделать, чтобы он выбирал из всей таблицы добавленные строки и потом уже их сравнивал?

P.S. Извиняюсь, что некорректно поставил вопрос, просто не знаю, как правильно его поставить.

**UPD 1**

Задача такова: есть, к примеру, 3 обращения от пользователя, далее в таблице есть wid (здесь находится id агента, его выбирает система автоматически, путём рандома), далее если wid = 1, то есть наш id 1, то нам выведет обращение пользователя.
Но проблема такова: идут в базе подряд 3 строки в обращением http://prntscr.com/5e4pi1, если поставить у id = 1, wid = 2, а остальные оставить, то почему-то уже не выводит обращения пользователя, то вопрос, почему так и как сделать, чтобы он не заострял внимание на 1 строке и проверял дальше строки и находил равное значения?

Comment: а словами задачу объясните плиз

Comment: объяснил...
приведи содержание таблиц и пример что бы ты хотел из нее вытащить (показать) при определенных условиях

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array - возвращает одну строку, для того чтобы выбрать все, нужно выбирать их в цикле:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT wid FROM tickets")))
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

Данный метод устарел (расширение mysql). лучше используйте mysqli или PDO(http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Например mysqli:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

$result = $db->query("SELECT wid FROM tickets");

$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```